# Matching the closest supported Resolution in an array, vb.net strings

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, pattern-matching

I have multiple devices that support different resolutions. I want to assign them all to the same resolution, or to the nearest resolution that it supports.

So, for example. If I have a desired resolution of "1280x720" and the device supports video resolutions of 1280x960 and 160x120, I'm going to want my code to pick the 1280x960.

The problem is that my current setup has attempted to pick the closest "distance" of the strings using the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

```
   'match reswidth to closest support 
    For i As Integer = 0 To ResArray.Count - 1
        'get string distance/difference amount
        LevDist(i) = LevenshteinDistance(ResArray(i), templateRes)
    Next

    Dim min = LevDist.Min()

    Dim x = ResArray(Array.IndexOf(LevDist, min))

    Return x
```

And the Lev function that I got off of a trusted site:

```
 Public Function LevenshteinDistance(ByVal s As String,
                ByVal t As String) As Integer
    Dim n As Integer = s.Length
    Dim m As Integer = t.Length
    Dim d(n + 1, m + 1) As Integer

    If n = 0 Then
        Return m
    End If

    If m = 0 Then
        Return n
    End If

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 0 To n
        d(i, 0) = i
    Next

    For j = 0 To m
        d(0, j) = j
    Next

    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To m

            Dim cost As Integer
            If t(j - 1) = s(i - 1) Then
                cost = 0
            Else
                cost = 1
            End If

            d(i, j) = Math.Min(Math.Min(d(i - 1, j) + 1, d(i, j - 1) + 1),
                       d(i - 1, j - 1) + cost)
        Next
    Next

    Return d(n, m)
End Function
```

My problem is, that just tells you the closest function in the strings. What if I had the same strings within it, but they were all in different places? It wouldn't pick the closest resolution but the closest string.  I don't think this is the best method.

Any suggestions on how to find the closest one in the array?

I saw another stack flow link with one for java, but I really didn't understand it. Nor could I get it to translate to vb.net.

([Stack flow php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805456/finding-closest-larger-resolution-with-nearest-aspect-ratio-in-an-array-of-resol))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably smarter ways to do this, but why not try something simple like comparing the product of your desired resolution with the products of the available resolutions and pick the one that is closest to your desired:

Desired:

```
1280 x 720 = 921600
```

Available:

```
1280 x 960 = 1228800
160 x 120 = 19200
```

Comment: Ooh, I didn't think of the product. That's good thinking. I had also tried smallest distance from just the width of the resolution, but this includes both.

Comment: I think it should work for you and should be a lot simpler than the Leventshtein distance.